# SIFT descriptors dimension

Tags: c++, c, opencv, sift

I want to know, if I can change the SIFT descriptors dimension , if so how can I do it. I know currently the dimension is 128, can we make is 128*4 or 124/4 something like this?

Update: I tried to change the SIFT_DESCR_WIDTH to 2, from 4 in  opencv / modules / nonfree / src / sift.cpp , but it doesn't change the dimension of descriptors, when I print descriptors.size() it prints 128.

Regards,

Comment: In depends on library you use.

Comment: means? sorry I did not understand. I am using opencv

Comment: Sorry, haven`t seen tags. No, you cannot change SIFT dimensions in OpenCV without changing the OpenCV source. Have you recompiled OpenCV with new parameters?
And what the purpose of the change?

Comment: How do I recompile it? can you please write in the answer, so that if it works I can accept the answer. The purpose is pretty simple. I just want to test, how it effects the performance and the effectiveness. thanks

Comment: The same way, as you have compiled it. Or how did you get it? Change that constant value, then do cmake & make for OpenCV. I will write an answer if it would work for :)
P.S. Actually, it wouldn`t change a lot for you - check original SIFT paper, http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf figure 8 - exactly about your question.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know, if it works.. I already read that paper. I just want to test myself. thats it. thanks anyways.

Comment: @old-ufo, it worked. Please write the solution, so that I can accept and mark the question as solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Done. Have you found more optimal SIFT dimension for your task than default?

Comment: more my task a lesser dimensional SIFT works perfect.

Comment: May be PCA-SIFT would suit your task even more? http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~yke/pcasift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change SIFT dimensions in OpenCV without changing the OpenCV source. So you have to change sources and recompile whole OpenCV or nonfree module.

Change that constant value, then do cmake & make for OpenCV.

P.S. Actually, it wouldn`t change a lot for you - check [original SIFT paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf), figure 8.

Answer (score 0):

you can try SURF descriptors, it support 64 dimension, and compute quicker than SIFT.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I know SURF is faster but I want to test with SIFT only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PCA (Principle Component Analysis) to try and go from 128 dimensions to 64 dimensions (or any dimensions you choose) after your descriptors have been extracted from your image. You're using C++, but I use Python for my OpenCV work and use `sklearn.decomposition` for this (I'm sure you can look up a similar library for C++). Basically it's similar to compression. Of course, you will lose some accuracy.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

Of course, any image you test against your data set will also need to have PCA run against it's descriptor vectors with the same dimension settings.